# How to chain a method that has a namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

If i have a function like

```
namespace.functionName = function() { 
   /// some code
 }
```

How do i use it in method chaining, for e.g:

```
$("#element1").show().namespace.functionName()
```

The above statement gives an error saying "cannot read property 'functionName' of undefined"

Comment: You can't use a function in chaining if it has nothing to do with the chain. `show()` needs to return an object which has a property `functionName`, or a property `namespace`. If it doesn't do that, you can't simply "pull" `namespace.functionName` into the chain.

Comment: Also in javascript there is no such concept as namespace (as far as I'm aware). You can structure your code, as there were, by placing your functions into objects.

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, the  attempt you are making doesn't make any sense. But to make function chaining happen, you can do it via

```
var namespace = {};

namespace.functionName = function() { 
   alert("hi");
 }

function show() {

    alert("do 1");
    /*just return the parent object of the namespace 
      assuming the namespace to be in global scope */
    return window;

}

show().namespace.functionName();
```

#### note

method chaining works by the idea that the first function we call returns an object which exposes the further methods to be called in chain. So in the case you are explaining, it is not possible without editing the `show()` method you are specifying.

Or as @RobG suggests, you could make a wrapper function which calls your required function and then returns the necessary object for chaining.

Comment: You could replace the *show* method with a wrapper that calls it then returns the required object. It would mess with calling it and expecting the default return though…

Comment: Yeah, but I think you should highlight the 'doesn't make any sense' part and stress that this is definitely not a recommendation. That might seem obvious to many, but ...

Comment: @mithunsatheesh : If i have code like your example, is show().namespace.functionName() a valid line of code?

Comment: @AliLane : No it wont work. Read the code to understand how chaining is implmented. Its not rocket science. You have to make a wrapper for show and return the object you need to chain after calling show method internally.

Answer (score 0):

for jQuery you can do

```
var yourNamespace = {};
yourNamespace.myFunction = function() { console.log("hey"); };
jQuery.fn.namespace = yourNamespace;
```

and then go crazy like

```
$("a:first").show().namespace.myFunction();
```

but notice that the context of the function will probably be the namespace object and not the jQuery item.